# How do I remove Onedrive from file path on Windows 10

Tags: windows-explorer, onedrive

I just removed onedrive (and unlinked my pc/account) from my computer however there is still a really irritating thing that I cant seem to remove and that is Onedrive is (still) in the path of my files (ex: Documents)

```
C:\Users\$user\OneDrive\Documents\Map
```

Is there any way to remove this? Do I maybe need to reinstall Onedrive and do something in the settings?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

You may examine and modify the two paths, system/global and user, by

*Control Panel > System > Advanced system settings > Advanced tab > Environment Variables button*

Click on the OneDrive path in the corresponding section, then click the *Delete* button.
When finished click *OK*.

You might need to logout and login for the update to take effect.

Comment: I did what you said but it didn't work. I still have onedrive within my paths (ex C:\Users\$user\OneDrive\Documents\)

Comment: What you report sounds impossible. Try it again, but only when booting in Safe mode.

Comment: I don't think OP is referring to any environment variables.